# vue.js : click a button, look through dom, find all classes with a specific class name and append a new class to that existing class list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So, i'm using Axios to pull an html file, and then take everything in that html file past the `<body>` tag and appending it to `{{htmlData}}` inside of a div in my template

looks like this:

```
<template>
     <somebutton> I click on</somebutton>
     <div id="some-container-name" v-html="htmlData">
        {{ htmlData }}
     </div>
</template>
```

```
     data: function() {
            return {
                htmlData:''
            };
        },
    methods: {
            pullView: function(html) {
                this.axios.get('http://someUrl.html').then(response => {
                    let corsHTML = response.data;
                    let htmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(corsHTML, "text/html");
                    this.htmlData = htmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
                })
            },
```

The user has an option to click on a button - the code then searches through the dom and then appends a classname to every existing `you-can-edit-me` class name from the html document that is pulled in via axios.

Does this make sense?

Because of how I'm pulling this content in, I don't really have the chance to bind anything to this content using Vue's :bind directive. My Google-fu has failed me and need some suggestions. Is it possible to edit this.htmlData and make the transformation in that object and then i guess re-render the data??

I don't want to pollute my work with jQuery and wondering if anyone else has done something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a parsed `htmlDoc`:

```
for (const element of htmlDoc.querySelectorAll('.you-can-edit-me')) {
  element.classList.add('additional-css-class');
}
```

inside your `pullView` method, before assigning it to `this.htmlData`.

Comment: So, the user will be able to view the doc - and if they want to edit it, they click the button that injects the new class - looks like i'll re-render the view after running that function.. Stand by.. gonna' try it out!

Comment: this is the right answer! It wasn't specific, but got me far enough! How do I buy you a beer?